# Updating yii2 grid whenever something happens to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a kartik grid which currently am updating using jquery with set timeout interval. This works but the problem is that it generates many http ajax requests and when i check on the taskmanager the Google chrome tends to use 25% of cpu..

This is what am currently doing.

```
echo DynaGrid::widget([
'columns' => $columns,
'showPersonalize' => true,
//'allowThemeSetting'=> false,
'options' => ['id' => 'trackyard'],
'gridOptions' => [
    'options' => ['id' => 'assignsolic'],
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'showPageSummary' => false,

    'pager' => [
        'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
        'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
        'maxButtonCount' => 10,
    ],
    'toolbar' => [
        ['content' => '{dynagrid}'],
        '{export}',
        '{toggleData}'
    ],
    'pjax' => true,
    'pjaxSettings' => [
        'options' => [
            'id' => 'wod',
           // 'enablePushState' => false,

        ],
        'loadingCssClass'=>false,
    ],

]
]);
```

This is the jquery code that updates the grid

```
function reloadgrid() {
  $.pjax.reload({container:"#trackyard-pjax"});
   }
 window.setTimeout(
  reloadgrid(),1000
  )
```

The above code works but is there better ways to call the above reload grid function anytime whenever something changes on the server to reduce the cp usage rate

Comment: Take a look at websockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `websocket` for real time updating of the client side when there is changes on server side. If you are using asp.net you can use `signalR` else you can go for `socket.io`